# Having trouble getting Arduino to work with Flask frame work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask, arduino, pyserial

This is a project for a club at school. I have a pretty basic Arduino program that blinks a LED at two different rates, depending on input received. I am really new to python so I don't really know what I'm doing. So far I wrote a small piece of code for this that works in just python. I just have it taking a user input and it writing it to the Arduino. It works great.

But I am meant to have a flask based GUI to control the Arduino. I set up two buttons to do this. When I modified the code to run with the flask app, the Arduino LED just blinks once and wont run the program. I'm not sure what is wrong. Here is my code:

Arduino:

```
 int led =13, data;
   void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(9600); // Set the baud rate
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // Set the onboard LED to output
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}
void loop()
{
while (Serial.available())
{
  data = Serial.read();
}
if (data =='1')
{
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); //turn LED on    
    delay(500); //wait for a second
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);//turn LED off
    delay(500); //wait for a second
}
if (data =='0')
{
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);//turn LED on
    delay(2000); //wait for a second
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);//turn LED off
    delay(2000); //wait for a second
}
}
```

HTML form submit buttons:

```
<form action ="/gui" method= "POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Blink Fast">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Blink Slow">
</form>
```

Python Flask

```
import serial
from flask import render_template, request
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/gui', methods=(['GET', 'POST']))
def hello_world():
    if request.method =='POST':
        request.form['submit']
        arduino_serial = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)  # Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
        if request.form['submit']== 'Blink Fast':  # if the entered data is blink fast
            print(b'1')
            arduino_serial.write(b'1')  # send 1 to arduino
        elif request.form['submit']=='Blink Slow':
            arduino_serial.write(b'0')  # send 0 to arduino
            print(b'1')

    return render_template('gui.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Last this is the code that worked:

```
import serial

Arduino_Serial = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)  # Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
print
Arduino_Serial.readline()  # read the serial data and print it as line
print("Enter 1 to ON LED and 0 to OFF LED")

while 1:  # infinite loop
    input_data = input()  # waits until user enters data
    print
    "you entered", input_data  # prints the data for confirmation

    if (input_data == '1'):  # if the entered data is 1
        Arduino_Serial.write(b'1')  # send 1 to arduino
        print("LED ON")

    if (input_data == '0'):  # if the entered data is 0
        Arduino_Serial.write(b'0')  # send 0 to arduino


print("LED OFF")
```

Comment: _wont run the program_ is there any error message? How do you start your flask app? Do you get any response when POSTing a request to `/` or `gui` route?

Comment: @Fian I start the flask app in pycharm, just using run. The web page opens with the buttons and when I click either of them I get this in the run part of the pycharm window . Not sure if it is an error:   127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2018 07:15:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2018 07:15:23] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
b'1'
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2018 07:15:27] "POST /gui HTTP/1.1" 200 -